# Disk character changes after restart

Tags: 16.04

I mounted the system on the sdb ，but when I restart the system , the disk character changes from sdb to sda

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That is 100% correct and intended.

Letters are assigned to partitions based on how quickly the partitions are ready when booting. Use the filesystem label, UUID, or disk ID to identify a partition. Not the device itself.

What is likely is that your boot partition had a filesystem check. That takes a few seconds. In that time your non-boot partition was ready and got the 1st letter. Then the boot partition got the 2nd letter.